# How to solve this error : System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

When I try to login to the system I got this error :

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

This is the code causing the error :

```
public ActionResult MagicalLogin(Users_web LogUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var details = (from userlist in db.Users_web
                       where userlist.user_name == LogUser.user_name && 
                             userlist.user_password == LogUser.user_password
                       select new
                              {
                                   userlist.custid,
                                   userlist.patient_no,
                                   userlist.user_fullname,
                                   userlist.user_name,
                                   userlist.user_kind_id,
                                   userlist.user_email,
                                   userlist.group_id,
                                   userlist.user_phone
                              }).ToList();
    }
}
```

What is the cause of this error ?

Comment: If this is the first call to EF, the error might not even be related to the concrete query. So first make sure there is no error in the entity model by invoking something simple like `_ = db.Model;` or `db.Users_web.Load();`

Comment: @IvanStoev , actually I deleted some tables from EF and added it back after that this error shows I think the error with columns mapping, now I take another fresh copy of my old project and now this error resolved no errors but now another issue raised its not redirected to the view when click login , I will update the question